# Steam hangs when downloading game content

Tags: windows-7, steam

I am helping a friend's son to install the game TotalWar, Rome II on a Windows 7 machine. We have the three discs retail version, but you need to use Steam to download 2 GB of files too.  However, when Steam tries to download them, it hangs.

Note, the boy has been using Steam for several weeks, for several games, without any issue.

Since his friends are able to install it on their machines, I suspect it is a local problem, maybe some permission issue, but I am not familiar with Windows 7 and I am not able to guess which one it could be.

Comment: Once the authentication code is added to the Steam library.  You should be able to install the game through Steam.  Please note this question is actually not on topic here at Superuser.  Furthermore you don't indicate the exact error, so how can the more skilled among us, help you locate a solution?

Comment: Ok, although I have seem other Steam question on SuperUser. Is there another more suitable forum? There is not an exact error, after we download/install from the first two discs, Steam takes over and after a few bits hangs. Question maybe is: which permissions of which folders do I need to check?

Comment: I read "some code" as it displays an error code. Its unlikely a permission error to be honest. Steam only installs data in a folder it has permission to place data in ( the Steam installation directory ). If you skip using the cds and just use steam to download and install the game is the friend's son able to install the game?  Its entirely possible this was simply done before the game as actually released on Steam.  Furthermore in the interest to avoid cross posting I won't answer the proper place for this question if.  It will simply be moved by a moderator to the correct place.

Comment: The question is actually on topic here – it's about software running on your computer, so you're fine, Mario.

Comment: Ok, thks slhck. To Romhound, Steam hangs after a 10/15', if I just try to donwload from remote.

Comment: What status has that game after running steam again? I would try to locate scraps of games files in steams directory at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\downloading` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common` folder.

Comment: It works now!!!. I just unchecked the checkbox 'only reading' for the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common, and restarted Window 7, and then it went downhill. I doubt whether to restart could have been enough, but I am not going to check :-)

Comment: By golly it actually was a permissions issue XD

Comment: @Mario, feel free to answer your own question as it may be helpful for others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

It works now!!!. I just unchecked the checkbox 'only reading' for the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common, and restarted Window 7, and then it went downhill. I doubt whether to restart could have been enough, but I am not going to check :-)